# How to extract data from google calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

i would like to extract data from google calendar to put it in another special calendar(that i will create) automaticaly.
So that when i have this calendar in an app it automatically extract data from user existing google calendar.

I've been searching for a while but didn't found nothing

Comment: The google API are actually very well documented: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ What is your problem exactly?

Comment: THx yeah ,i've just seen it,

Comment: THx yeah ,i've just seen it,but my poroblem is how to create a new calendar personnalised by extracting my own data automatically from my google calendat and put it in it (after that i will add things) bit ill now i don't know how

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I found it to be very confusing, gives me loads of errors, very bad jar organisation, just terrible examples and they give java projects as it was android app..

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees The examples are all split for >8 languages, Android and Java are two seperate ones. Using gradle (as described in the quickstart) should not bring you to a bad jar organisation. Here you can see how to setup the API for java: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java and here is an example to create an event: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events So what is missing?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind their samples are just hideous.. I am trying just now to set up 1 sample code from their github and it produced like 50 errors.. I mean how is it even possible? Most of the jars are missing even I included every single of them.. I did exactly what they stated in the instructions..You probably have to be google debeloper to understand their way of coding. I dont get it why they can simply make url requests with 3 secret keys for example to get your data with json..